# Magento checkout success page: get some order information

Tags: magento

I need some basic information on my Magento checkout success page to check some conversions through my shop. For that I need the total price of the order and all article IDs.

While searching I found a code to get the last order:

```
<?php
    $_customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
    $order->load($lastOrderId);
?>
```

But how can I get the total price and all article IDs (seperated by ,).

I'm quiet new to Magento, so everything is a bit confusing to me.

Can somebody help me?

Thank you.

Greetings from Germany,
Raisis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get order total by `$order->getData('base_grand_total');`

in order to get all articles (loop through) you need to do,

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $items) {
    $items->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code to get order object and order total, it's cleaner

```
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$total = $order->getGrandTotal();
?>
```